# Pausing Javascript execution until button press

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a visualization of a Sudoku creator for my Algorithms class (in Javascript).  The algorithm works great, but I'm having trouble finding a way to pause execution.

Currently, I'm using `prompt()` to pause, but that's bulky and annoying.  Is there any way to pause until another function is run (via HTML button) other than a continuous `while` loop?

I can post code, but I don't think it's needed.  I'm not currently using jQuery, but I can if needed.

Comment: no, because `window.stop()` doesn't stop script execution, it stops window from loading, similar to browser's stop button.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var flag = true;
function foo(){
    if (flag){
        // Do your magic here
        ...
        ...
        setTimeout(foo, 100);
    }
}

function stop(){
    flag = false;
}
<input type="button" onclick="stop();" value="stop it!!!" />
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JseE2/2/)

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having a 'while()' loop cranking along in the background.  Is there any other way?  (If not, this looks pretty good)

Comment: You mean `setTimeout(foo)`, not `setTimeout(flag)`.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to pause is a function which would otherwise keep looping, I've come up with a good solution:

**HTML**

```
<div id="stuff">Doing stuff</div>
<button id="pause">Pause/Resume</button>
```

**JS**

```
var paused = false;

document.getElementById('pause').addEventListener('click', function() {
  paused = !paused;
  if (!paused) {
    next();
  }
});

function doStuff() {
  // Do whatever you want here, then invoke next() for the next iteration of that function, for example:
  // (Note that the window.setTimeout is NOT part of the solution)
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('stuff').append('.');
    next();
  }, 300);
}

function next() {
  if (!paused) {
    doStuff();
  }
}

doStuff();
```

**CodePen:** https://codepen.io/liranh85/pen/baVqzY?editors=1010